# How do I specify the root module directory in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas, travis-ci

I have code that restores a few small excel files in python using pandas, and performs some data analysis on them. I'm now trying to setup testing of my code, but I'm running into some trouble and I can't find a decent answer when searching around.

Here's the directory structure of my code:

```
my_project/
    __init__.py
    code/
        __init__.py
        analysiscode.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        testcode.py
    data/
        datafile.xlsx
```

I was originally running `analysiscode.py` from the `code` directory, so I was restoring the data file by specifying the path like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('../data/datafile.xlsx')
```

However, now when I try running tests on the code from the module root directory (i.e. `my_project`), the path specified to go up one directory before looking in the data directory no longer works.

Here is an example of the error message:

```
my_project$ nosetests
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/datafile.xlsx'
```

For this particular case, I could always specify the full path, but I'm looking for a more general solution so that someone else can download this code and still have it work.

Is there a way of specifying the `my_project` directory in python? In other words, is there a way of saying something along the lines of

```
mydatadir = my_project/data
df = pd.read_excel(mydatadir+'datafile.xlsx')
```

That way I could run analysis code either from the `my_project/code` directory OR the `my_project` directory without needing to know the full path to `my_project`?

Comment: try importing the os module then use `os.chdir("..")` to switch to the last directory then run the command as `df = pd.read_excel('data/datafile.xlsx')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, running the code from the `my_project` directory with `os.chdir("..")` and the dots removed from the filename in the call to `read_excel` searches for `my_project/../data/datafile.xlsx`. That is, it searches for a data directory that is one level up from `my_project`, which fails.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Can you give me the output of `os.getcwd()` after the `os.chdir("..")` part?

Comment: To generalize it, I'm working in `/Users/me/projects/my_project`. Running `print(os.getcwd())` after `os.chdir("..")` returns `/Users/me/projects`

Comment: Weren't you originally in the code directory?

Comment: Originally, yes. But now I am trying to run `analysiscode.py` from the `my_project` directory. That way I can run tests using something like nose through travis-ci.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the module root path using `__file__` after importing `my_project`:

```
In [1]: import my_project
In [2]: print(my_project.__file__)
Out[2]: /Users/me/projects/my_project.__init__.py
```

And getting rid of the `.__init__.py` to get to the module root directory through a little string manipulation:

```
In [3]: my_project_dir = '/'.join(str(my_project.__file__).split('/')[:-1])
In [4]: print(my_project_dir)
Out[4]: '/Users/me/projects/my_project/'
```

Applying this to my code example above, the data can then be restored no matter what the current working directory is like this:

```
import my_project
import pandas as pd
my_project_dir = '/'.join(str(my_project.__file__).split('/')[:-1])
df = pd.read_excel(my_project_dir+'data/datafile.xlsx')
```

I've tested this out, and I can now successfully run `analysiscode.py` from within the `code` directory, as well as from within the `my_project` directory, and running `nosetests` from the `my_project` directory works as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you into the base directory (my_project) as long as you're in my_project or any of its subdirectories. After this code, you can run commands like 
`df = pd.read_excel('data/datafile.xlsx')`.

```
import os
my_dir = "my_project" #Root Directory
while os.getcwd().find(my_dir) >= 0:
    os.getcwd("..") #Go back until you are out of the my_dir
os.chdir(my_dir) #Go back into my_dir
```